# How do you automatically change HTML Title according to its file name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So for example the file name would be Hello.html, how do you make the html title turn to "Hello" automatically? Is this possible with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Is there a reason you want this automated? You can just set a <title> tag in the head of your html. If you want to do this with javascript, you can parse the window path and set document.title that way.

Comment: `document.title = document.href.split('/').pop();`

Comment: Yes because I am making 1 chapter = 1 html file. And there are tons of chapters I have to work with. Edit: How do you exclude the '.html'?

Comment: `.replace('.html', '')`, but I don't get why you can't just put a different `<title>` tag in each page, as @David suggested...

Comment: There are more than 200 chapters resulting more than 200 html files. I want each title to contain the chapter number they are currently in. Manually editing it would be really time consuming..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the title by this :

```
document.title = (location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)).replace('.html','');
```